# Facing Issue with React Native Credit Card Scanner

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a code written in react native for scanning credit card info. I followed https://github.com/kayla-tech/react-native-card-io. The scanner is able to read my card number, but fails to read my expiry and cvv. Given Below is the Code.

```
componentDidMount() {
CardIOUtilities.preload();
}

alertfunction(out){
this.props.navigator.replace({id:'CreditCardPayment'})
console.log(out);
} 

    <View>
      <CardIOView
        style={styles.preview}
        hideCardIOLogo={true}
        allowFreelyRotatingCardGuide={true}
        scanInstructions={'Hold card here. It will scan automatically.'}
        scannedImageDuration={2}
        detectionMode={CardIOView.automatic}
        scanExpiry={true}
        didScanCard={result => this.alertfunction(result)} />                  
    </View>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using detection mode :automatic, 
use detection mode :cardImageAndNumber because automatic mode start as CardIODetectionModeCardImageAndNumber, 
but fall back to CardIODetectionModeCardImageOnly if scanning has not succeeded within a reasonable time.

the same docs in here what you are using.
Check the nice documentation here:
https://github.com/Kerumen/react-native-awesome-card-io